Nginx reverse proxy cant find webapp on localhost or be accessed from external machine
I have a simple rocket webserver, with several endpoints, in particular
#[get("/ping")]
pub fn ping() -> &'static str {
    "pong!"
}

I have Rocket.toml file in the project directory with following contents:
[debug]
address = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8000
workers = 1
keep_alive = 5
read_timeout = 5
write_timeout = 5
log = "normal"
limits = { forms = 32768 }

[staging]
address = "0.0.0.0"
port = 8000
workers = 1
keep_alive = 5
read_timeout = 5
write_timeout = 5
log = "normal"
limits = { forms = 32768 }

[release]
address = "0.0.0.0"
port = 8000
workers = 1
keep_alive = 5
read_timeout = 5
write_timeout = 5
log = "critical"
limits = { forms = 32768 }

I have nginx installed with a .conf file in /etc/nginx/sites-available direcory containing:
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

which is symlinked to the file of same name in /etc/nginx/site-enabled directory. I made sure to restart nginx service after I added said files. I, then, configured my ufw by running ufw allow 'Nginx Full', also reloading it for changes to take effect. Then I have opened screen instance where I run my rocket app with ROCKET_PROFILE=debug cargo run .
  >> IP header: X-Real-IP
   >> limits: bytes = 8KiB, data-form = 2MiB, file = 1MiB, form = 32KiB, forms = 32KiB, json = 1MiB, msgpack = 1MiB, string = 8KiB
   >> temp dir: /tmp
   >> http/2: true
   >> keep-alive: 5s
   >> tls: disabled
   >> shutdown: ctrlc = true, force = true, signals = [SIGTERM], grace = 2s, mercy = 3s
   >> log level: normal
   >> cli colors: true
Warning: found value for deprecated config key `log`
   >> in Rocket.toml TOML file
   >> key has been by replaced by `log_level`
Warning: found value for deprecated config key `read_timeout`
   >> in Rocket.toml TOML file
   >> key has no special meaning
Warning: found value for deprecated config key `write_timeout`
   >> in Rocket.toml TOML file
   >> key has no special meaning
Warning: found set deprecated profile `staging`
   >> profile `staging` has no special meaning
 Routes:
   >> (ping) GET /ping
 Fairings:
   >> Shield (liftoff, response, singleton)
️ Shield:
   >> Permissions-Policy: interest-cohort=()
   >> X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
   >> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
 Rocket has launched from http://127.0.0.1:8000
GET /ping:
   >> Matched: (ping) GET /ping
   >> Outcome: Success(200 OK)
   >> Response succeeded.
GET /ping:
   >> Matched: (ping) GET /ping
   >> Outcome: Success(200 OK)
   >> Response succeeded.

After returning to the original terminal window I checked if I can access the rocket app on localhost by running curl 127.0.0.1:8000/ping which worked as intended. I, then, have run same command using 0.0.0.0:80/ping which returned "404 page not found html". When I curl for the "0.0.0.0:80" I get usual nginx landing page as expected. When I try to access any of the urls from remote device requests timeout and no entries are generated in access or error logs of nginx.
As several answers to similar questions suggested I have checked whether site-available contents are included into default nginx configuration file, and tried adding or removing slash and scheme of the proxy pass atribute in my .conf file.

Most probably you have the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file which acts as the default server for the HTTP requests; read "How nginx processes a request" article for the details. Either add default_server flag to your listen directive or use the server_name directive and test your requests including Host HTTP header, e.g. curl -H "Host: testdomain.local" ...

@IvanShatsky this was exactly the issue. Thank you!
